# Fail2Ban failregex after office hours

Tags: fail2ban

How can we run specific `failregex` after office hours, and ignore during office hours as some of the conditions may detect wrongfully.
e.g this could be from users:

```
failregex = ^\.\d+ \[WARNING\] sofia_reg\.c:\d+ SIP auth challenge \((REGISTER|INVITE)\) on sofia profile \'[^']+\' for \[.*\] from ip $
```

https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Fail2Ban

Log e.g:

```
2020-12-28 12:53:55.204495 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:1794 SIP auth challenge (INVITE) on sofia profile 'internal' for [aaa@xx.xx.xx.xx] from ip 1xx.3x.8x.1xx
```

Comment: This seems like a bad idea.  But you could do it by symlinking to the appropriate config and restarting with a cron script.

Comment: failregexes should be defined so that they match log entries corresponding to _failures_. This is why the one included with fail2ban triggers on `SIP auth failure`. Set `mode = normal` in your `[freeswitch]` jail to solve this problem without resorting to time conditions or other bizarre hackery. (assuming you use the filters included with fail2ban).

Comment: @MichaelHampton failregexes for failure already enabled and are working fine and banning ips accordingly on `SIP auth failure`. If I add this `SIP auth challenge \((REGISTER|INVITE)\)` in regex then it bans legit users also as there are ips brute forcing with `SIP auth challenge (INVITE)` shown in logs